# Can Grahas be influenced willingly?

Tags: astrology, navagraha, horoscopes

So based on how Sanjay Rath defines, a **Graha** is something that causes **Grahana**. Or in other words, they eclipse (Not in a necessarily negative way) the houses they sit on and force the **Jataka** to do karma of certain types. The horoscope, as a whole, is essentially the celestial map of **Prarabdha**.
The Grahas positions in anyone's chart describes what karma a person ought to do in this life.

My question is, "Is it possible to influence these Grahas by the virtue of their house position or sign position, willingly in natal or divisional charts?" In simple words, can a siddha reposition the Grahas in his own or someone else's horoscope? If yes, then what is the method he needs to follow?

Comment: Then can you please elaborate on what does a horoscope show?

Comment: How is that possible? .. the Graha positions will be fixed by virtue of birth. If Graha positions can be changed like that then we will instantly start looking different, behaving differently.

Comment: A true Siddha can't change the position of Grahas but definitely can stop Nava Graha influence to his disciples life.  A true example would be Gyanasambantha murthy - one of 63 Nayanmars who stopped influence of Grahas to cure a king. You can't change Grahas but can stop its influence

Comment: That makes sense. Can you point me towards any literature which deals with this in detail?

Comment: Whom are you asking? Use username

Comment: @akshay: I asked you only. Apologies, I am new to the platform.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/ravana-and-his-astrological-endeavours)?

Comment: Its there in Periya Purana @SameerAnand ..

Comment: @YDS Yes, something like that. So indeed it's possible. Any ideas how? <Haha>

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Thanks. I would certainly check it out.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for : https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=103&v=pPt8fyLvdqg